# Why is the memory of a qwebpage's test increasing all the time?

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit, qwebpage

Consider:

```
    QString urls[] = {
        QString("http://www.sina.com")
    };
    int len = 1;
    QWebSettings::setMaximumPagesInCache(0);
    QEventLoop loop;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
        QWebPage *page = new QWebPage;
        page->settings()->setAttribute(
                    QWebSettings::AutoLoadImages,
                    false);
        page->settings()->setAttribute(
                    QWebSettings::PrintElementBackgrounds,
                    false);
        page->settings()->setAttribute(
                    QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled,
                    false);
        QString url = urls[i % len];
        cout << "requesting " << url.toStdString() << endl;
        connect(page, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)),
                &loop, SLOT(quit()));
        page->mainFrame()->load(url);
        loop.exec();
        disconnect(page, 0, 0, 0);
        QWebSettings::clearMemoryCaches();
        page->settings()->clearMemoryCaches();
        connect(page, SIGNAL(destroyed()),
                &loop, SLOT(quit()));
        printLog(page->mainFrame()->toHtml());
        page->deleteLater();
        loop.exec();
    }
```

When this test is executed, the memory increase from about 40 MB to about 700 MB. It looks like a memory leak exists in my code. But it seems that all the objects are deleted. Why is this?

Comment: This code reminds me why smart pointers were invented...

Comment: Not sure why exactly you use a heap object rather than stack here, but how about subclassing the QWebPage, and reimplement the ctor and dtor with debug prints to see if they are called in pair properly?

Comment: thanks, I checked they are called in paired. other suggestion?

Comment: I would try to split the inner loop into two parts, so just one loop.exec() to pin the issue further down.

Comment: Also, which version are you using? Is it Qt 4 or Qt 5? Which minor version?

Comment: the version is Qt 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a known issue already in 2009. Unfortunately, the person who had brought up the issue did not go further to actually file a bugreport. You can read the corresponding thread here:

http://marc.info/?l=webkit-dev&m=124888472218111&w=2

I would suggest to go ahead and create a bug report if it is still present with Qt 5.2.

Note that, in an ideal world, as written, you should not have a heap object for this operation, although it is slightly off-topic as it would not fix your issue. Yet, it is better to be aware of that a stack object here would do your job without the manual deletion headache.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It just a test program. In the actual case, I will not create it in heap.

Comment: @user2651976: I would suggest to report a bug if you do not have time and energy for testing a later version, preferably even from the stable branch.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to rewrite your code in the following way:

```
QString urls[] = {
    QString("http://www.sina.com");
};
int len = 1;
QWebSettings::setMaximumPagesInCache(0);
QEventLoop loop;
QWebPage page;
for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
    page.settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::AutoLoadImages, false);
    page.settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PrintElementBackgrounds, false);
    page.settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled, false);
    QString url = urls[i % len];
    cout << "requesting " << url.toStdString() << endl;
    connect(page, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    page.mainFrame()->load(url);
    loop.exec();

    QWebSettings::clearMemoryCaches();
    page.settings()->clearMemoryCaches();
    printLog(page.mainFrame()->toHtml());
}
```

It is much simpler and does not require explicit memory allocation.

Comment: This does not address the concern why the memory leak happens. The OP did not ask for solving the issue, but _why_ the memory leak happens. That is why I also only just noted the stack vs. heap in the comment 1-2 hours before.

Comment: thank you for your help. I run your code in my machine, the memory usage is still increasing all the time and it seems that increasing will not stop...can any one tell me why?

Comment: @user2651976, the problem is probably in QWebKit implementation and not in your code: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/11105 . Did you try to use much recent version of QWebKit that comes with Qt5?

Comment: the version of my Qt is 5.1